# What's the actual use of the Atomics object in ECMAScript?

Tags: javascript, specifications, ecmascript-2017

The [ECMAScript specification](https://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf) defines the **Atomics object** in the section **24.4**.

Among all the global objects this is the more obscure for me since I didn't know about its existence until I didn't read its specification, and also Google hasn't many references to it (or maybe the name is too much generic and everything gets submerged?).

According its official definition

> The Atomics object provides functions that operate indivisibly (atomically) on shared memory array cells
>   as well as functions that let agents wait for and dispatch primitive events

So it has the shape of an object with a number of methods to handle low-level memory and regulate the access to it. And also its public interface makes me suppose it. But what's the actual use of such object for the end-user? Why is it public? Are there some examples where it can be useful?

Thank you

Comment: Atomics are part of ES8, not ES6.

Comment: What do you mean by end-user?

Comment: http://2ality.com/2017/01/shared-array-buffer.html and https://tc39.github.io/ecmascript_sharedmem/shmem.html#intro should be some good reads. Instead of searching for "atomics", try the term "shared memory".

Comment: @Bergi I know! But I didn't have enough score to create the tag, so I used that. For end-user I mean the developers who make real world applications

Comment: @Bergi thank you for the links!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Atomics are for synchronising WebWorkers that share memory. They cause memory access into a SharedArrayBuffer to be done in a thread safe way. Shared memory makes multithreading much more useful because:

- It's not necessary to copy data to pass it to threads
- Threads can communicate without using the event loop
- Threads can communicate much faster

Example:

```
var arr = new SharedArrayBuffer(1024);

// send a reference to the memory to any number of webworkers
workers.forEach(worker => worker.postMessage(arr));

// Normally, simultaneous access to the memory from multiple threads 
// (where at least one access is a write)
// is not safe, but the Atomics methods are thread-safe.
// This adds 2 to element 0 of arr.
Atomics.add(arr, 0, 2)
```

SharedArrayBuffer was enabled previously on major browsers, but after the [Spectre incident](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectre_(security_vulnerability)) it was disabled because shared memory allows implementation of nanosecond-precision timers, which allow exploitation of spectre.

In order to make it safe, browsers need to run pages a separate process for each domain. Chrome started doing this in version 67 and shared memory was re-enabled in version 68.

Answer (score 9):

Atomic operation is "everything or nothing" group of smaller operations.

Let's have a look at

```
let i=0;

i++
```

`i++` is actually evaluated with 3 steps

1. read  current `i` value
2. increment `i` by 1
3. return the old value

What happens if you have 2 threads doing the same operation? they can both read the same value `1` and increment it at the exact same time.

## But this and Javascript, isn't it's single threaded?

Yes! JavaScript indeed single threads but browsers / node allows today usage of several JavaScript runtimes in parallel (Worker Threads, Web Workers).

Chrome and Node (v8 based) creates [Isolate](https://v8docs.nodesource.com/node-0.8/d5/dda/classv8_1_1_isolate.html) for each thread, which they all run in their own `context`.

And the only way the can `share memory` is via `ArrayBuffer` / `SharedArrayBuffer`

## What will be the output of the next program?

Run with node > =10 (you might need `--experimental_worker` flag)

`node example.js`

```
const { isMainThread, Worker, workerData } = require('worker_threads');

if (isMainThread) {
  // main thread, create shared memory to share between threads
  const shm = new SharedArrayBuffer(Int32Array.BYTES_PER_ELEMENT);

  process.on('exit', () => {
    // print final counter
    const res = new Int32Array(shm);
    console.log(res[0]); // expected 5 * 500,000 = 2,500,000
  });
  Array(5).fill(null).map(() => new Worker(__filename, { workerData: shm }));
} else {
  // worker thread, iteratres 500k and doing i++
  const arr = new Int32Array(workerData);
  for (let i = 0; i < 500000; i++) {
    arr[i]++;
  }
}
```

The output **might be** `2,500,000` but we don't know that and in most of the cases it won't be 2.5M, actually, the chance that you'll get the same output twice is pretty low, and as programmers we surely don't like code that we have no idea how it's going to end.

This is an example for race condition, where n threads race each other and not synced in any way.

Here comes the `Atomic` operation, that allows us to make arithmetic operations from start to end.

Let's change the program a bit and now run:

```
const { isMainThread, Worker, workerData } = require('worker_threads');


if (isMainThread) {
    const shm = new SharedArrayBuffer(Int32Array.BYTES_PER_ELEMENT);
    process.on('exit', () => {
        const res = new Int32Array(shm);
        console.log(res[0]); // expected 5 * 500,000 = 2,500,000
    });
    Array(5).fill(null).map(() => new Worker(__filename, { workerData: shm }));
} else {
    const arr = new Int32Array(workerData);
    for (let i = 0; i < 500000; i++) {
        Atomics.add(arr, 0, 1);
    }
}
```

Now the output will always be `2,500,000`

## Bonus, Mutex using Atomics

Sometimes, we wish to an operation that only 1 thread can access at the same time, let's have a look at the next class

```
class Mutex {

    /**
     * 
     * @param {Mutex} mutex 
     * @param {Int32Array} resource 
     * @param {number} onceFlagCell 
     * @param {(done)=>void} cb
     */
    static once(mutex, resource, onceFlagCell, cb) {
        if (Atomics.load(resource, onceFlagCell) === 1) {
            return;
        }
        mutex.lock();
        // maybe someone already flagged it
        if (Atomics.load(resource, onceFlagCell) === 1) {
            mutex.unlock();
            return;
        }
        cb(() => {
            Atomics.store(resource, onceFlagCell, 1);
            mutex.unlock();
        });
    }
    /**
     * 
     * @param {Int32Array} resource 
     * @param {number} cell 
     */
    constructor(resource, cell) {
        this.resource = resource;
        this.cell = cell;
        this.lockAcquired = false;
    }

    /**
     * locks the mutex
     */
    lock() {
        if (this.lockAcquired) {
            console.warn('you already acquired the lock you stupid');
            return;
        }
        const { resource, cell } = this;
        while (true) {
            // lock is already acquired, wait
            if (Atomics.load(resource, cell) > 0) {
                while ('ok' !== Atomics.wait(resource, cell, 0));
            }
            const countOfAcquiresBeforeMe = Atomics.add(resource, cell, 1);
            // someone was faster than me, try again later
            if (countOfAcquiresBeforeMe >= 1) {
                Atomics.sub(resource, cell, 1);
                continue;
            }
            this.lockAcquired = true;
            return;
        }
    }

    /**
     * unlocks the mutex
     */
    unlock() {
        if (!this.lockAcquired) {
            console.warn('you didn\'t acquire the lock you stupid');
            return;
        }
        Atomics.sub(this.resource, this.cell, 1);
        Atomics.notify(this.resource, this.cell, 1);
        this.lockAcquired = false;
    }
}
```

Now, you need to allocate `SharedArrayBuffer` and share them between all the threads and see that each time only 1 threads go inside the `critical section`

Run with node > 10

`node --experimental_worker example.js`

```
const { isMainThread, Worker, workerData, threadId } = require('worker_threads');


const { promisify } = require('util');
const doSomethingFakeThatTakesTimeAndShouldBeAtomic = promisify(setTimeout);

if (isMainThread) {
    const shm = new SharedArrayBuffer(Int32Array.BYTES_PER_ELEMENT);
    Array(5).fill(null).map(() => new Worker(__filename, { workerData: shm }));
} else {
    (async () => {
        const arr = new Int32Array(workerData);
        const mutex = new Mutex(arr, 0);
        mutex.lock();
        console.log(`[${threadId}] ${new Date().toISOString()}`);
        await doSomethingFakeThatTakesTimeAndShouldBeAtomic(1000);
        mutex.unlock();
    })();
}
```

Answer (score 7):

If you have some complex computation you may need [WebWorkers](https://www.codementor.io/cedpoilly/why-web-workers-hy9e7pjjb), in order for your main script to continue its work while heavy things are done in parallel.

**The problem that Atomics solve is how WebWorkers can comunicate between each other (easily, fast and reliably)**. You can read about ArrayBuffer, SharedArrayBuffer, Atomics and how you can use them for your benifits [here](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2017/06/a-crash-course-in-memory-management/).

**You shouldn't bother about it if:**

- You are creating something simple (e.g. shop, forum etc)

**You may need it if:**

- You want to create something complex or memory consuming (e.g [figma](https://www.figma.com/) or [google drive](https://www.google.com/intl/ru_ALL/drive/))
- You are looking to work with `WebAssembly` or `webgl` and you want to optimize performance
- Also you may need it if you want to create some complex Node.js module
- Or if you are creating a complex app via [Electron](https://electronjs.org/) like [Skype](https://www.skype.com/en/) or [Discord](https://discordapp.com/)

Answer (score 4):

In addition to what Arseniy-II and Simon Paris stated, Atomics are also handy when you embed JavaScript engine into some host application (to enable scripting in it). Then one can directly access shared memory from different concurent threads simultaneously, both from JS and from C/C++ or whatever language your host application is written, without involving JavaScript API for access on C/C++/OtherLanguage side.

Answer (score 2):

I have coded a script using Web Worker and SharedArrayBuffer to demonstrate the use of Atomics:

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html><head></head><body><script>
   var arr = new SharedArrayBuffer(256);
   new Int16Array(arr)[0]=0;
   var workers=[];
   for (let i=0; i<1000; i++) workers.push(new Worker('worker.js'));
   workers.forEach(w => w.postMessage(new Int16Array(arr)));
</script></body></html>
```

Then with a separate file worker.js:

```
// worker.js
onmessage = function(e) {
    e.data[0]++;                 // last line is 981 only? wth?!
    //Atomics.add(e.data,0,1);   // last line is exactly 1000. right...
    console.log(e.data[0]);
}
```

As you can see, without the mutex guaranteed by Atomics, the addition would not be correctly carried out sometimes.