# What does the Atomics object do in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, atomic

This is the [MDN documentation on Atomics](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Atomics).

I can't understand how an atomic object could be used in a real-life situation or if they are for internal use only (i.e. not meant to be called at all).

**What does the `Atomics` object do in JavaScript? How can I use them?**

Comment: [It's a new ES2017 feature.](http://2ality.com/2017/01/shared-array-buffer.html)

Comment: Exact duplicate of [What's the actual use of the Atomics object in ECMAScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45870869/1048572)

Comment: @AlexisTyler: Why did you post a bounty on this question, rather than on the linked duplicate?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the actual use of the Atomics object in ECMAScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45870869/whats-the-actual-use-of-the-atomics-object-in-ecmascript)

Answer (score 43):

This feature was introduced with ECMAScript 2017. `Shared Memory` and `Atomics` introduce a new memory model that allows multi-agent programs to communicate using atomic operations that ensure a well-defined execution order even on parallel CPUs. This specification also includes new static methods on `Object`: `Object.values`, `Object.entries`, and `Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors`.

The main idea is to bring some sort of multi-threading feature to JavaScript so that JS developers can write high-performance, concurrent programs in the future by allowing to manage memory by themselves instead of letting JS engine manage memory.

This is done by a new type of a global object called `SharedArrayBuffer` that essentially stores data in a shared memory space. So this data can be shared between the main JS thread and web-worker threads.

You simply use `SharedArrayBuffer` and the data is instantly accessible by both the main thread and multiple web-worker threads.

But sharing memory between threads can cause race conditions. To help avoid race conditions, the `Atomics` global object is introduced. `Atomics` provides various methods to lock the shared memory when a thread is using its data. It also provides methods to update such data in that shared memory safely.

Let's wait some new abstract library which will use those API's right.

[shared memory and atomics](http://2ality.com/2017/01/shared-array-buffer.html)

[a cartoon intro to SharedArrayBuffers](https://hacks.mozilla.org/category/code-cartoons/a-cartoon-intro-to-sharedarraybuffers/)

[JavaScript: From Workers to Shared Memory](https://lucasfcosta.com/2017/04/30/JavaScript-From-Workers-to-Shared-Memory.html)

[ECMAScript 2019. Memory Model](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-memory-model)

[Avoiding race conditions in SharedArrayBuffers with Atomics](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2017/06/avoiding-race-conditions-in-sharedarraybuffers-with-atomics/)

Also recommend to see the [tutorial](https://github.com/tc39/ecmascript_sharedmem/blob/master/TUTORIAL.md) about shared memory in ECMAScript.

Answer (score 5):

Dangers of multithreaded programming

- Deadlocks
- Unpredictable
    order of read-write operations
- Data fragmentation

To solve the previous problem what can we do?

**Use the atomic option**

The Atomics object provides atomic operations such as add, sub, and, or, xor, load, store etc. as static methods. They are used with SharedArrayBuffer objects.

For more information and a good example:
Source:https://www.slideshare.net/barakdrechsler/atomic-javascript

https://jirak.net/wp/introducing-new-javascript-optimizations-webassembly-sharedarraybuffer-and-atomics-in-edgehtml-16/

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/atomics-or-in-javascript/

For good resource  chapter 12 SharedArrayBuffer in:

`Phang, C. L. (2017). An Effective Guide to Modern JavaScript:(ECMAScript 2017/ES 8). Chong Lip Phang.`

```html
<iframe frameborder="0" scrolling="no" style="border:0px" src="https://books.google.com.tw/books?id=--gvDwAAQBAJ&lpg=PP3&ots=zqgshUnSQa&dq=atomic%20%20SharedArrayBuffer%20%20for%20javascript&lr&pg=PA80&output=embed" width=500 height=500></iframe>
```